# Radio Buttons in angular dynamic forms

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I am new working with angular dynamic forms and I have a problem with radio buttons, when I select a radio button option, the value of the radio button selected is not reflected in the instance of FormGroup. To illustrate the situation I will show you the relevant code:

I have two components:

- **dynamic-form**
- **dynamic-form-question**

**dynamic-form** receives a list of answers thanks to the `toFormGroup(answers):FormGroup` method, that answers list are rendered as radio buttoms in the **dynamic-form-question** component, also **dynamic-form** builds a form which is transmitted to the **dynamic-form-question** component.

below the code of each component:

**dynamic-form.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
  <div *ngFor="let answer of answers$ | async">
    <app-question [answer]="answer" [form]="form"></app-question>
  </div>
</form>
```

**dynamic-form.ts**

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-form',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form.component.css'],
  providers: [ AnswerControlService ]
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() answers$: Observable<AnswerBase<any>[]>;
  form: FormGroup;
  payLoad = '';

  constructor(private qcs: AnswerControlService, private service: DynamicFormService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form= new FormGroup({});
    this.answers$.subscribe(a=>this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(a));
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.payLoad=JSON.stringify(this.form.value);
  }
```

**dynamic-form-question.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
<label [attr.for]="answer.id">{{answer.label}}</label>

<div [ngSwitch]="answer.controlType">

  <input *ngSwitchCase="'radio'" [formControlName]="answer.controlName"
          [id]="answer.id" [type]="answer.type" [value]="answer.label">
</div> 
<div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{answer.label}} is required</div>
```

**dynamic-form-question.ts**

```
   @Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-form-question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form-question.component.css']
})
export class DynamicFormQuestionComponent {
  @Input() answer: AnswerBase<any>;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Input() currentQuestion:Question;

  get isValid() { 
    return this.form.controls[this.answer.controlName].valid;
  }
}
```

When I select a radio button options, two problems occur:

1. The selection of options are not mutually exclusive, even though the answer.controlName property has the same value for all option.

[image]

2. When I call the `onSubmit()` method, selecting some, or all the options. No property of value is assigned to the control. Next I show you, the sample of my console when `onSubmit()` method has been called.

[image]

I hope someone can help me with this, because I've been trying for hours and I do not know why this happens.Thank you very much!

Comment: It's impossible for a radio button group (with same name attribute) to allow multiple selections. Perhaps you have placed your radio button groups within different <FORM> tags?

Comment: @ Michael Niño The code that I have is the same that is in the publication of this question, it is as if the controls of the template were not connected with the form. I do not know if maybe it is that when the dynamic-form-question component is built, it is initially constructed with an empty form

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Have child component which has some radio buttons connected to the parent formGroup, but the values never get reflected, in my case the formgroup is passed as an @Input to the child, but it doesn't work also.

Answer (score 3):

Use the same behaviour as the dropdown example in the [dynamic form documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form)

**question-radio.ts**

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

export class RadioQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'radio';
  options: {key: string, value: string}[] = [];

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.options = options['options'] || [];
  }
}
```

**question.service.ts**

```
new RadioQuestion({
        key: 'sex',
        label: 'Sex',
        type: 'radio',
        options: [
          {key: 'Male',  value: 'm'},
          {key: 'Female',  value: 'f'}
        ],
        required: true,
        order: 4
      })
```

**dynamic-form-question.html**

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">
      <label *ngFor="let opt of question.options">
        {{opt.key}}
        <input
          type="radio"
          [name]="question.key"
          [formControlName]="question.key"
          [value]="opt.value">
      </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had the same challenge. My form is based on a JSON file, bu it is more or less the same logic